# $http service does not show data in browser from json file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I write both controller.js and HTML file but when load it console.log() show the objects from JSON file but data cannot show in the browser.

HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>AngularJs|Http Service</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="controller16.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="people">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in users">{{person.Name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

controller.js: -

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('people', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/Angularjs/12/database.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.records;
        console.log(response);
    });
});
database.json: -{
    "records": [{
        "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
        "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }, {
        "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }, {
        "Name": "Around the Horn",
        "City": "London",
        "Country": "UK"
    }, {
        "Name": "B's Beverages",
        "City": "London",
        "Country": "UK"
    }, {
        "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "City": "Luleå",
        "Country": "Sweden"
    }, {
        "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
        "City": "Mannheim",
        "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
        "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
        "City": "Strasbourg",
        "Country": "France"
    }, {
        "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
        "City": "Madrid",
        "Country": "Spain"
    }, {
        "Name": "Bon app'",
        "City": "Marseille",
        "Country": "France"
    }, {
        "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
        "City": "Tsawassen",
        "Country": "Canada"
    }, {
        "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
        "City": "Buenos Aires",
        "Country": "Argentina"
    }, {
        "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }, {
        "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
        "City": "Bern",
        "Country": "Switzerland"
    }, {
        "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
        "City": "São Paulo",
        "Country": "Brazil"
    }]
}
```

the above code only shows me a blank screen.show help me to figure out.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/Angularjs/12/database.json` not accesible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `resonse.data.record` instead of `response.record`

```
$http.get("http://127.0.0.1/Angularjs/12/database.json").then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data.records;
    console.log(response.data);
});
```